# How to get absent user list in mysql..?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have tables as below

```
employees
-----------------------
empId  Name   MobileNumber
1      Name1  12345
2      Name2  123456
3      Name3  1234567
4      Name4  12345678

attendance
-------------------------------------------
Id    MobileNumber    Type    attendance_datetime
1     12345           IN      2017-05-31 10:04:42
2     123456          IN      2017-05-31 10:05:29
3     1234567         IN      2017-05-31 10:06:15
4     12345           OUT     2017-05-31 18:05:15
5     123456          OUT     2017-05-31 18:10:15
6     1234567         OUT     2017-05-31 18:15:15
```

I want to get absent user list for a particular date how to get it ?

I have tried below query but not gettting result.

```
select * from employees e,attendance a where e.MobileNumber = a.MobileNumber AND DATE(a.attendance_datetime) =  str_to_date('31-05-2017', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use left outer join:

```
SELECT * FROM employees e
LEFT JOIN attendance ON employees.MobileNumber = attendance.MobileNumber
AND DATE(attendance_datetime) = '2017-05-31'
WHERE attendance.Id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks but what about date If I append date conditions it does not give result...

Comment: Just add the date condition to the join like in the updated query in my answer.